# how does filesystem benchmark tools measure time?

Tags: c, linux, iozone

I want to measure the running time of a specific system call, for example, I want to know a `pread` need how many time on both CPU and I/O.

Which function should I use?

Now I use`times`, and it works.

`gettimeofday` is get the current time, and that may not just calculate the running time of a specific process, right?

`clock` is return the CPU time this program used so far, does this include the I/O time? If there are other programs running, will this influence the time of this function? I mean something like switching running process.

`getrusage` seems like a ideal one, but it also returns the `CPU` time of a specific process.

Does anyone know how benchmark tools like iozone calculate `system calls` time? I've read its code, and still have no idea.

Comment: iozone uses `gettimeofday` (full time; wall time; astronomic time. this has almost highest resolution) and `getrusage` (cpu time, sometimes rounded to 1-10 ms units) on posix platforms (and may use `times`), according to its sources (iozone.c). It calls both functions before and after I/O operations and calculate difference. For measuring syscall time there is also `strace -T`, which uses `gettimeofday` and tries to estimate and subtract its overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `times(2)`.

Comment: I've tried this function, `pread` a 131072 bytes buffer, and the total ticks is always zero, is that normal? I've changed that to 1310720, still always zero, sometimes it is 1. does `times` really include I/O time?

Comment: Are you looking at the user time or the system time?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about that. I want to get the total time of a system call. like how many time the program spend on read 131072 bytes from hard disk. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams